# Is there a JavaScript component for embedding HTML docs in a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking for something like Viewer.js but for loading a separate HTML document.

So I want something that has pagination concepts, and this doesn't have javascript in it, just CSS and HTML. It's not cross domain, it's fed back from a Web API.

Not sure why there's downvotes.

Comment: If you're asking how to do this in HTML5, maybe you could use [`<iframe>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)?

Comment: or http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_object.asp

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `iframe`?. It should do exactly what you need - load a separate HTML into your web page.

You cannot create something like `Viewer.js` because you can have problems with loaded JS and CSS, that is why `iframe` is a safety option (and probably the only one)

Comment: Keep in mind that if its cross-domain, you will not be able to manipulate it or get data from it.